Criterias for variable substitution in identities
consider the following question, if $x+y+z = xyz$, prove that
$$\frac{2x}{1-x^2} + \frac{2y}{1-y^2} +\frac{2z}{1-z^2} =\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\times\frac{2y}{1-y^2}\times\frac{2z}{1-z^2}$$
this can be done using taking LHS, taking common denominators and using the original identity to get RHS, even though this method is tedious the identity can be proven, but the problem is this question was under a trigonometry question, my other approach to solve it using trigonometry was as follows
Let $x,y,z = \tan(2x), \tan(2y), \tan(2z)$ such
$$x+y+z = xyz$$
$$\tan(2x)+\tan(2y)+\tan(2z) = \tan(2x)\times \tan(2y)\times \tan(2z)$$
$$\frac{2\tan(x)}{1-\tan^2 (x)} + \frac{2\tan(y)}{1-\tan^2 (y)} +\frac{2\tan(z)}{1-\tan^2 (z)} =\frac{2\tan(x)}{1-\tan^2 (x)}\times\frac{2\tan(y)}{1-\tan^2 (y)}\times\frac{2\tan(z)}{1-\tan^2 (z)}$$
Let $\tan(x), \tan(y), \tan(z) = x,y,z$ such
$$\frac{2x}{1-x^2} + \frac{2y}{1-y^2} +\frac{2z}{1-z^2} =\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\times\frac{2y}{1-y^2}\times\frac{2z}{1-z^2}$$
My idea here is to substitute $x$ with $\tan(2x)$ and such is that since $x$ can be any number, what I put instead of $x$ doesn't matter if that variable or function covers the whole domain too, so $2x, x^2, e^x, \log(x), \tan(x)$ wont matter, but then i realized the domain of tan(x) doesn't have $\pi/2$, and similar constrains for other functions, but no other way comes to my mind, and the question doesn't say anything about the domain of $x,y,z$.
Further speaking generally, if there is some identity $f(x,y,z) = g(x,y,z)$, if we substitute the variables with another variable or a function, are there are restrictions of criteria that I should follow, for example of $h(x)$ is some other function, if $f(x,y,z) = g(x,y,z)$ holds true does that also mean that $f(h(x),h(y),h(z)) = g(h(x),h(y),h(z))$ also holds true?

The restrictions on $x, y, z$ are implied by the question so you should not worry about them. It's also OK to use your tangent substitution because the range of the $\tan$ is all reals. Range is important here and not the domain.

As noticed in the comments, we can make any change of variables such that the new variables

have the same range of the previous over a specified domain
satisfy the same constraint given by the specific equation/inequality

In your example it is not completely correct assume

$\tan x =x$
$\tan y =y$
$\tan z =z$

since you are using the same $x, y, z$ of course we can use same symbols but strictly speaking we are assuming

$\tan a =x$
$\tan b =y$
$\tan c =z$

with, for example, $a,b,c \in \left(-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2\right)$ if $x,y,z \in \mathbb R$.
Another valid choice, in this case, could be for example $x=a^3$, $y=b^3$, $z=c^3$ but not $x=a^2$, $y=b^2$, $z=c^2$.
